# Kinect SDK c++ grab and press gesture

Tags: c++, kinect, gesture-recognition, kinect-sdk

I've been working with Kinect for a few months and I've used OpenNI and Kinect for Windows SDK since then. A few months ago, when I started using it, I was usinf C# with WPF to create menus that a user could use gestures to interact with them using WPF. Using WPF it's pretty easy to detect grab gestures, swipes and press gesture (This is done in a trasparent way to the programmer), but since I've migrated to C++, I have no clue how to detect them. Which functions of the Kinect SDK are used to do this or where can I find a tutorial regarding this matter?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 0):

I realize it's an old question, but I had the same problem and haven't found an answer. What I did found was this post on MSDN forums stating that those gestures are integral part of WPF/XAML and cannot be used without it. Person from url i linked below said: "I would say that press, pan and zoom as you found them are no "general gestures" out of the box, only interactions with some WPF/XAML controls inside a KinectRegion." Good thing is that those functions are not that hard to implement.

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/59cf4671-98cc-4fe5-a3e0-6ecc612cde3c/swipe-gesture-in-v2-sdk?forum=kinectv2sdk